# Predicting from inferred parameters in pymc3

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression, bayesian, pymc3

I am trying to understand this from a non-Bayesian background.

In linear regression or blackbox machine learning tools the work flow is something like the following.

1. Get data
2. Prepare data
3. Model data (learn from it [or part of it, the training set])
4. Test model (usually on the test set)
5. If model is good according to some metric, goto 6, else
   investigate and revise work.
6. Model is good enough; use it to predict/classify, etc.

So let's say I use pymc3 to try to understand the relationship between advertising expenditure and revenue from goods sold. If all stages from 1 to 5 go well, then in frequentest statistics used in R and machine learning packages such as scikit-learn, I only need to pass new unseen data to the learned model and invoke the predict method. This will usually print out a predicted value of Y (revenue from goods sold), given some unseen value(s) of X (advertising expenditure), with some confidence intervals or some other margin of error still being taken into account.

How would one go about doing that in pymc3? If I end up with many slopes and many betas then which should I use for predicting? And wouldn't taking the mean of all slopes and all betas to use be like throwing away a lot of otherwise useful learned knowledge?

I find if difficult to understand how sampling from the posterior can help in this. One can imagine bosses who need to be told about an expected revenue from goods sold Y figure given some advertising expenditure X amount, with some confidence and error margins. Aside from plotting, I don't know how sampling from posterior can be incorporated into a management report and make it useful for cash flow planning by interested parties.

I know some of us are spoiled coming from R and maybe scikit-learn, but wouldn't it be nice if there was a predict method that dealt with this matter in a more uniform and standardized way?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

One way of taking into account the uncertainty in parameters when making predictions with a model is to use the [posterior predictive distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Posterior_predictive_distribution). This distribution tells you the probability of a new observation, conditioned on the data that you used to constrain the model parameters. If the revenue is Y, the advertising expenditure is X, the model parameters are theta and the data used to constrain the model are X', then you can write

[image]

The left hand side is the probability of attaining revenue Y given an expenditure X, and the data used to constrain the model X'. This is the posterior predictive distribution of your model, and should be used when making predictions. p(Y | X, theta) is the probability of revenue Y given some set of model parameters theta and the expenditure X. p(theta | X') is the posterior distribution on the model parameters given the data that you used to constrain the model.

When using software like `pymc3`, you obtain samples from p(theta | X'). You can use these to do the integral above in a Monte-Carlo fashion. If you have N samples from the posterior in your MCMC chain, then you can do the sum

[image]

in other words, you compute p(Y | X, theta_n) for every set of parameters in your MCMC, and then take the average (note that this isnt the same as `taking the mean of all slopes and all betas' as you mentioned in your question, because you are computing the average of a pdf rather than the parameters themselves). In practice this should be easy to code, you just need to implement the function p(Y | X, theta) and then plug in your posterior parameter samples, then take the mean at the end. This gives you the fairest representation of your model prediction given your MCMC sampling.